# Webform : how to count and live display results

Tags: sql, drupal-webform

Update (that one works)

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($nid);
  if ($node->type == 'webform') {
    $count = db_result(db_query('SELECT count(*) FROM {webform_submissions} WHERE nid = %d', $nid));
    $atelier_1 = "sources" ;
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM {webform_submitted_data} WHERE data LIKE \"".$atelier_1."\" ;";
    $count_atel_1 = db_result(db_query($sql));
  }
}
echo $sql;
echo $count_atel_1;
?>

This webform has been submitted <?php print $count ?> times.
```

---

We'd like to use a webform so that our students should register on some workshops.

The webform works great. Now we'd like to display live the number of students that are already register in on of the workshops so that the other should know if there remains some possibilities of registration (each workshop can only accept 20 students at the same time)

I'm trying with that that doesn't work ($atelier_1 = "sources" ;) is the name of one workshop :

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($nid);
  if ($node->type == 'webform') {
    $count = db_result(db_query('SELECT count(*) FROM {webform_submissions} WHERE nid = %d', $nid));
    $atelier_1 = "sources" ;
    $count_atel_1 = db_result(db_query('SELECT count(*) FROM {webform_submitted_data} WHERE data LIKE %d', $atelier_1');
  }
}

echo $count_atel_1;
?>
```

Any help or suggestion welcome

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can show that live, is by creating an ajax in drupal, or with drupal behaviours, or with javascript.